# Getting different results using Ruby IRB and files on method merge/code block

Tags: ruby, merge, block, irb

When I run these two Ruby scripts I got two different answers. Also, if I run the first script on irb, I get the same results as the second script (and I know the results on second script and irb are correct). Am I missing any anything on the first script? Thanks for the help.

#### Ruby version: 1.9.3

#### Text Editor: TextWrangler

```
h1 = {"n1"=> 00, "n2"=> 44}
h2 = {"n2"=> 66, "n3"=> 88}
```

#### first script -- Results: `{"n1"=>0, "n2"=>66, "n3"=>88}`

```
puts h1.merge(h2) do |key, old, new|
  if old < new
     old
  else
     new
  end
end
```

#### second script -- Results: `{"n1"=>0, "n2"=>44, "n3"=>88}`

```
puts h1.merge(h2) {|key,old,new| old < new ? old : new}
```

Comment: in which conditions do you get `{"n1"=>0, "n2"=>66, "n3"=>88}` ?

Comment: I should get {"n1"=>0, "n2"=>66, "n3"=>88} only if old greater than new. if old is less than new the answer should be {"n1"=>0, "n2"=>44, "n3"=>88}

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the first case Ruby thinks block belongs to `puts`, not to `merge`, use `{}`:

```
p h1.merge(h2) { |key, old, new|
  if old < new
   old
  else
   new
  end
}
```

**UPDATE**: You can find details in the [Programming Ruby](http://phrogz.net/ProgrammingRuby/language.html#blocksclosuresandprocobjects) book.

Comment: Thanks Victor. However, for blocks shouldn't I use either do/end or {}? I am confused because on irb I could run the first script and get the right answer.